# Is it ever said what bloomed from Penny Maowkavitz's grave?

Tags: short-stories, nights-dawn-trilogy

I've just finshed reading the short fiction *A Second Chance at Eden* by Peter F. Hamilton, from the book of the same name. In the scene of Penny Maowkavitz's funeral, it's said that a seed of her own creation was planted on her grave:

> A small shallow hole had been dug at the centre of the glade. Pieter Zernov stepped up to it and put a large jet-black seed in the bottom; it looked like a wrinkled conker to me.
>
> ‘It was Penny’s wish that she should finish up here,’ he said loudly. ‘I don’t know what the seed is, except it was one of her designs. She told me that for once she had forgone function, and settled for something that just looks damn pretty. I’m sure it does, Penny.’

Another character also mention it later in the story:

> I await with some eagerness to see what it is that will bloom from her grave.

Unless I'm mistaken, what ended up blooming from the grave is not revealed.

I know this story is a snapshot that takes place in the same universe as the author's series *The Night's Dawn Trilogy*, but I never read these books. Did the author or another of his stories ever described what the seed bloomed into?